# Appium Tests in Actual Mobile App Dev Project

Tags: gradle, junit, testng, appium, bitrise

I have been doing some hands on labs in Appium for a couple of weeks now, using tutorials on YouTube, Udemy and other sources. I am pretty much comfortable in running those tests using sample APKs in these tutorials.

Now, I would like to also understand details on how Appium tests would be run on an actual Mobile App Dev project using JUnit or TestNG where we do not work on the APK, but rather that the automated tests be triggered during build using IntelliJ and Gradle. Running the automated tests manually does not make sense, because these tutorials do that only rather than the tests being kicked off during build. Any of you'll with live experience with Bitrise - if you can also give your inputs, it would really help since in my project Bitrise would be used as well.

Any inputs on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

PS - I am newbie tester :)

Answer (score 0):

i use Bitrise, but only use them as a continuous integration (CI), I don't use mobile devices there. I use aws device farm to run automated tests.

When you said

> Running the automated tests manually does not make sense

it depends: project size, test suite size, how many new features are released on each new pull request (PR), how many new features are released in each new version, execution **time** of everything, **Costs**

The value of having automated tests that fire on every push/commit , PR or Release should be evaluated.

For example, if you use the [testing pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html) concept:

- Unit Tests (owner is same developer), check each build
- Service Tests (owner: backend and automatic QA) check each build
- User Interface Tests (QC and automatic QA) verify each new version or Release